# UIImageView Cache policies - AFNewtorking

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking

I have several UIImageView's in my app that I use AFNetworking's `setImageWithURL` to populate an image from my server.  The documentation says that this method uses the standard UIImageView cache policy.  My issue is that if I update an image on my server, the image does not get updated in the app soon enough.  Even if I close out of the app and restart.  If I want images to update I have to reinstall the app, which clears the cache and brings in new images.  Obviously this is not a desired effect for the user.

AFNetworking's cache is private, so I don't have direct access to it in the UIImageView + AFNetworking category.  Any thoughts on clearing the whole app cache?  How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `+ (AFImageCache *)af_sharedImageCache` method, most easily by copying it into the interface file `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`.  This will expose the singleton NSCache subclass.  Then you can call `– removeObjectForKey:` or `– removeAllObjects` to remove the image or all images, respectively.

If you don't want to do this, consider that the image is cached using the `NSHTTPURLResponse` object as the key.  You could create a different key by appending some random value to the URL (for example, you could append `?garbage=4H5G789H35G89H`).  However, this would basically waste memory as you'd be caching images that would never be retrieved.

Finally, you may want to [submit an enhancement request](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues?state=open) (or code one yourself) to expose the cache or make caching optional.

Comment: No problem.  Just curious, which approach did you take?

Comment: Created a method in UIImageView+AFNetworking.h called clearAFImageCache that calls [[[self class] af_sharedImageCache] removeAllObjects] and then call [UIImageView clearAFImageCache]

Comment: Neat.  If you like it, consider submitting it to the AFNetworking project.  Other similar libraries, like SDWebImage have built-in cache clearing methods.