# UICollectionView scroll performance using AFNetworking to load images

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, afnetworking, uicollectionview

I have read quite a few of the UICollectionView posts about poor scrolling, but none seem to directly apply or they are still unanswered.

I'm using `AFNetworking` to asynchronously load the images (95px squared) onto each cell and then when the images are scrolled into view again, the image is restored from cache (as verified by the response code given as 0 instead of 200).

Here's what I've tried:

- Commented out `weakCell.photoView.image = image;` so the images aren't draw on screen and the scrolling was smoother (still stuttered a little during the HTTP get)
- Removed all of the AFNetworking code from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and the scrolling was much smoother (even with the custom cell shadows, etc. still being drawn on screen)
- When I draw only the cell view (with the shadows) on screen, scrolling is very smooth for 100 cells. As soon as I start drawing the images on screen, scrolling is very poor on my device and it's even noticeable on the simulator. Instagram has very smooth scrolling for hundreds of cells on their profile view, so I'm trying to get close to their performance.

**Are there any ways that I can improve any of my code below in order to improve scrolling performance?**

Here is my cell code:

```
#import "PhotoGalleryCell.h"

@implementation PhotoGalleryCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        // Setup the background color, shadow, and border
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.25f alpha:1.0f];
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
        self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.0f);
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;

        // Make sure we rasterize for retina
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

        // Add to the content view
        self.photoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.photoView];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    self.photoView.image = nil;
    self.largeImageURL = nil;
}
```

And here is my UICollectionView code:

```
#pragma mark - Collection View Delegates

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [zePhotos count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PhotoGalleryCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kPGPhotoCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Get a reference to the image dictionary
    NSDictionary *photoDict = [[zePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"];

    // Asynchronously set the thumbnail view
    __weak PhotoGalleryCell *weakCell = cell;
    NSString *thumbnailURL = [[photoDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSURLRequest *photoRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailURL]];
    [cell.photoView setImageWithURLRequest:photoRequest
                          placeholderImage:nil
                                   success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                       weakCell.photoView.image = image;
                                   }
                                   failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                       NSLog(@"Error retrieving thumbnail... %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                   }];

    // Cache the large image URL in case they tap on this cell later
    cell.largeImageURL = [[photoDict objectForKey:@"large"] objectForKey:@"url"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPhotoDetail" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Have you had any success in resolving this issue? I'm hitting the same thing and would much appreciate a follow-up if you have.

Comment: @Tres Sorry, but I have just had to accept the performance hit for now.  AFNetworking states that it's been optimized for any subclass of UIScrollView (such as UITableView or UICollectionView) but it seems to be the reason why the UI performance is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a shadowPath to your cell init, it should improve performance, that's the code I used on one of my project to add a rounded shadowPath (see the UIBezierPath methods for more choice)

```
self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.frame.bounds
                                              byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                                    cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10, 10)].CGPath;
```

Moreover if I remember correctly AFNetworking doesn't resize the image returned from the server, so it could have an impact on the quality of your image (despite the scale method you added to the UIImageView), I recommend dispatching the returned image to resize it if you want as so :

```
CGSize targetSize = cell.photoView.bounds.size;
[cell.photoView setImageWithURLRequest:photoRequest
                      placeholderImage:nil
                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                                       CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;
                                       CGFloat imageWidth = image.size.width;

                                       CGSize newSize = weakCell.imageView.bounds.size;
                                       CGFloat scaleFactor = targetSize.width / imageWidth;
                                       newSize.height = imageHeight * scaleFactor;

                                       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
                                       [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
                                       UIImage *small = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                                       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

                                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                                           weakCell.photoView.image = small;
                                       });
                                   });
                               }
                               failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                   NSLog(@"Error retrieving thumbnail... %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                               }];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As I said in the OP: When I draw only the cell view (with the shadows) on screen, scrolling is very smooth for 100 cells. As soon as I start drawing the images on screen, scrolling is very poor on my device and it's even noticeable on the simulator.  So, it appears to be an issue with AFNetworking image caching.

Answer (score 0):

Code inspection looks good, though I bet it is the compositing of the shadow which is adding a good deal to the lag. The way you figure out exactly what is causing the delay is to use the Time Profiler tool in Instruments. [Here are the docs from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html).

Comment: When I draw *only* the cell view (with the shadows) on screen, scrolling is very smooth for 100 cells.  As soon as I start drawing the images on screen, scrolling is very poor on my device and it's even noticeable on the simulator.  Instagram has very smooth scrolling for hundreds of cells on their profile view, so I'm trying to get close to their performance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you scroll quickly you're starting up hundreds of network requests at the same time.  If you have the image cached, display it immediately.  If you don't, only start the download when the table view slows down.

You can use something like this:

```
//Properties or Instance Variables
NSDate *scrollDateBuffer;
CGPoint scrollOffsetBuffer;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{   
    NSTimeInterval secondsSinceLastScroll = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:scrollDateBuffer];
    CGFloat distanceSinceLastScroll = fabsf(scrollView.contentOffset.y - scrollOffsetBuffer.y);

    BOOL slow = (secondsSinceLastScroll > 0 && secondsSinceLastScroll < 0.02);
    BOOL small = (distanceSinceLastScroll > 0 && distanceSinceLastScroll < 1);

    if (slow && small) {
        [self loadImagesForOnscreenRows];
    }

    scrollDateBuffer = [NSDate date];
    scrollOffsetBuffer = scrollView.contentOffset;
}
```

You will want to call `loadImagesForOnscreenRows` in other methods, like when new data comes in, `viewWillAppear`, and `scrollViewDidScrollToTop`.

Here's an example implementation of `loadImagesForOnscreenRows`:

```
- (void)loadImagesForOnscreenRows
{
    @try {
        for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
            // load your images
            NSURLRequest *photoRequest = …;
            if (photoRequest) {
                [cell.photoView setImageWithURLRequest:…];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception when loading table cells: %@", exception);
    }
}
```

I have this in a try/catch block because in my experience `[UITableView -visibleCells]` isn't reliable - it occasionally returns deallocated cells or cells without a superview.  If you make sure this method is only called when the table is not scrolling quickly, it shouldn't impact scroll performance too much.

Also, note that the AFNetworking UIImageView category doesn't expose the cache object.  You'll need to modify it slightly to check if you already have an image cached; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16903375/1445366) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Note that my answer includes info about UITableView, and you're using a UICollectionView.  The same answer applies, since UICollectionView follows the same design patterns.

Comment: Sorry for the late response!  AFNetworking is supposed to already be optimized for any subclass of UIScrollView such as the ones you list, so this should already be taken care of.